# How the Message processor will send the reply to out sequence?

Tags: wso2-esb

I am using a case of wso2 esb (4.8.1) message store and message processor. 
I am using ActiveMQ as a message store. I am successfully storing the message in queue and also message processor successfully deliver it. The reply that come from the backend on deliver I want to pass that to out sequence.

find my message processor configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messageProcessor xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
              class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor"
              name="Forwarder_Cluster"
              messageStore="cluster_jms">

   <parameter name="max.delivery.attempts">2</parameter>
   <parameter name="interval">3000</parameter>
   <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="message.processor.reply.sequence">out</parameter>

</messageProcessor>
```

I am getting an error **Scheduled Message Processor Could not find the message consumer to clean up.**

Any ways to do this

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate sequence for handling the response. Default sequence want support your use case. Please refer [Store and Forward Using JMS Message Stores](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Store+and+Forward+Using+JMS+Message+Stores) for more details.

Best Regards,
Vanji